# How can I show differents popups on a page based on the user has submitted a form or not?

Tags: javascript, html

To begin with I'm super new in JavaScript.

I have a page with a "fake" registration form (it is a standard form, it don't save any data to a user database or something) and I also have a page with a "restricted area" (the only barrier is a JavaScript pop-up) that can only be accessed if the user has submitted that form.

I have to do it using cookies and this is my goal:

If the user enter to the restricted area without fill any form it has to show a pop-up saying "You are not registered" or something like that and once the user fill the form and the user come back to that page it has to show another pop-up saying "Welcome".

All of this I have to do it using cookies, I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I have all necesary html pages but I don't know how to start doing this so in relation to JavaScript nothing because I can't find code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look into JavaScript cookies. Here is a helpful link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

I recommend that you create a cookie with a boolean value that corresponds to whether the user has signed up or not. Then, if that boolean value is true, you can continue with the page load, and if the boolean value is false (or doesn't exist), you can redirect the user to the sign up page.